# Pop up Run windows in autoit to be open through send keys

Tags: autoit

Both `send("#r")` and `send("{LWIN down}{RWIN down}{R down}{RWIN up}{LWIN up}{R up}")` is not working for me. I have open RUN windows screen  using `autoit`.

Answer (score 1):

[`ShellExecute()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm) is perfect for calls like this. But if you really want to go through a Run Prompt window you can use this too :

```
Local $shell = ObjCreate("shell.application")
$shell.FileRun()
```

The benefit is that you don't have to use an emulated-keyboard-stroke to open the Run Prompt because <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> could be linked to an other command launcher, it's cleaner that way.

Comment: Aurélien Achat's solution has one more benefit: it opens the 64 bit version of the Run box, if your system is 64 bit.

Comment: Right now i'm using eclipse to run autoit, and I have no idea where and how to use this shell script.Can anyone help me please:-)

Comment: You have to put the code at the same place you wanted to use `send("{LWIN down}{RWIN down}{R down}{RWIN up}{LWIN up}{R up}")`. I don't know how you managed to use eclipse as an AutoIt script launcher, so if you don't use the classic SciTE4AutoIt, it won't be easy to help you.

Comment: Yes, I tried with SciTE4AutoIt too.                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("File Path of AutoIt.exe");   This is the syntax right? But still its not working.

Comment: The command you gave is for launching AutoIt, not SciTE; I was talking about using SciTE instead of Eclipse.
But this is not your main problem I think : you said "remote server", and I wonder if your problem is not linked to the remote access software. Where do you want to launch the RunPrompt, and through which software ? RDP ? VNC ? TeamViewer ?

Answer (score 0):

This works like expected:

```
Send('{LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP}')
```

Your question was'nt clear. You want to open the windows Run-box with its native function call, is it?
Do it so:

```
ShellExecute(@SystemDir & '\rundll32.exe', 'shell32.dll #61')
```

Comment: Whats your Windows version? It works perfect in Windows-XP, Windows 7 Pro x64. (Thats, what I can test). May be you've Windows 10? This OS is not really a friend of AutoIt.

Comment: i  am using windows 7 only..Control send is working fine. I want to open RUN windows through code..Any  help is accerpted.

Comment: I have to login to my remote server and access those applications. Till now I can login successfully using autoit but I have to open RUN of remote server. Any suggestion is acceptable. Since I'm new and I am learning, sorry for my mistakes:-)